# How to request mapping with request parameters properly with search in java?

Tags: java

I am coming to a problem where I am trying to request map with request parameters, basically I need to do a GET request to this url `jobs?autocomplete=0100` and for some reason I am getting all of my `/jobs` instead, can you help me to solve this issue. thanks!

```
@RestController
//@RequestMapping(value = "/jobs", params = "autocomplete")
public class AutoCompleteController {

    private AutoCompleteService autoCompleteService;

    private EntityManager em;

    public AutoCompleteController(AutoCompleteService autoCompleteService, EntityManager em) {

        this.autoCompleteService = autoCompleteService;
        this.em = em;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/jobs", produces = "application/json")
    public List<AutoComplete> getSalary(
            @RequestParam(name= "autocomplete", required = true) String autocomplete,
            @PathVariable("jobClassCd") String jobClassCd) {

        return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(jobClassCd);

    }





    public void getAllSalaries(HttpServletResponse res, HttpServletRequest req) {

        Stream<AutoComplete> stream = autoCompleteService.retrieveAllSalaries();
        DataStreamUtility.streamObjects(stream, res, em);



    }


}
```

> Service:

```
@Service
public class AutoCompleteService {


    private AutoCompleteRepository autocompleteRepository;

    public AutoCompleteService(AutoCompleteRepository autRepo) {
        this.autocompleteRepository = autRepo;
    }

    public List<AutoComplete> retrieveSalary(String jobClassCd) {
        List<AutoComplete> salaries = autocompleteRepository.findByJobClassCd(jobClassCd);


        if (salaries.size() <= 0) {
            throw new SalaryNotFoundException(jobClassCd);
        }

        return salaries;
    }


    public Stream<AutoComplete> retrieveAllSalaries() {

        return autocompleteRepository.streamAll();


    }



}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not delete your question when you get your answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a `@RequestParam` annotated parameter for the method handling the request:

`GET localhost:8080/jobs?job_id=456`

```
@GetMapping("/jobs", produces = "application/json")
public Book getJob(@RequestParam("job_id") Long id) {
    return repo.findJobById(id);
}
```

So, your code would look like this:

```
@GetMapping("/jobs", produces = "application/json")
public List<AutoComplete> getSalary(
    @RequestParam("autocomplete", required = true) String autocomplete,
    @PathVariable("jobClassCd") String jobClassCd) {

    return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(jobClassCd);

}
```

Comment: hi. can you show me an implemention to my code above, please?

Comment: you are trying to put @RequestMapping on class, however, you need to do it on the method if you want to get the parameter. I will update my code as if you accept parameter on the method level

Comment: So, I get comment out the @RequestMapping on the class and added the method that you have posted. Still getting all the jobs, when I do GET on `localhost:8080/jobs/?autocomplete=456`

Comment: and PathVariable says `Cannot resolve path variable jobClassCd in request mapping `

Comment: and `String autocomplete` is never used.

Comment: I even do. `/jobs?autocomplete=456` and I dont get anything back. no json result.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Can you post an example of how the autocomplete works? Because I showed you how to get it from the request, but I did not update your code to actually return something different, because I do not know what exactly your end goal is. What is the retrieveSalary() method does and how should it be affected by autocomplete param?

Comment: the autocomplete is using the jquery autocomplete where when user search for value and it will show a autocomplete dropdown. And for retrieveSalary() please see updated question.

Comment: basically, what I want to accomplish is when I do a GET request `jobs?autocomplete=010` I want it to look in the database to see what has starting with 010 or any value that ?autocomplete="" has.